# Can I create a subclass derived from metaclass like this?

Tags: python

I tried to create a class that inherit from a metaclass declared in the superclass, I did like that:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


class Database(object):
    """
        Class that holds all data models classes and functions
    """
    def __init__(self, wenDbPath = "test.db"):
        self.engine = create_engine('sqlite:///' + "c:/"+wenDbPath, echo=False)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        **self.Base** = declarative_base() # This returns a metaclass.
        self.Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)
        self.session = self.Session()

    class Element(**self.Base**):
        __tablename__ = 'elements'
        idNumber = Column(String(255), primary_key=True)
        smallDiscription = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
        longDiscription = Column(String())
        webLink = Column(String())

        def __init__(self, idNumber, smallDiscription, longDiscription, webLink):
            self.idNumber = idNumber
            self.longDiscription = longDiscription
            self.smallDiscription = smallDiscription
            self.webLink = webLink
        def __repr__(self):
            return "<Element ('%s : %s')>" % (self.idNumber, self.smallDiscription)
```

Python gives me the following message

> class Element(self.Base):
>   NameError: name 'self' is not defined

How can I do something like this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no `self` in the class scope when the outer class is defined. Why do you want to do something like this, anyway?

Comment: I want to group all my data classes in one place

Comment: How about using the usual method and put all the classes in a module?

Comment: I was thinking about that seriously, this could be the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class body is evaluated before `__init__` runs.  Since `Base` doesn't depend on `__init__` parameters, you can evaluate it at class evaluation time:

```
class Database(object):
    ...
    Base = declarative_base() # This returns a metaclass.
    class Element(Base):
        ...
```

Note that you're using `Base` as a superclass, not a metaclass; metaclass syntax is `__metaclass__ = Base` or `(metaclass=Base)` depending on version.  See [What is a metaclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python)